# Getting unique values in dictionary Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Hello I am trying to get the unique values in a dictionary. I have a working code but I wanted to see if there was a cleaner solution.

"test.csv" looks like this:

```
Test1,1,BALL 
Test1,2,APPLE 
Test1,3,APPLE 
Test,4,APPLE
Test,6,BALL
```

And the script looks like this:

```
name_dist=dict()
with open('test.csv','r')as f:
    spamreader=csv.reader(f,delimiter=",")
    next(f)
    for row in spamreader:
        if row[2].strip() in name_dist:
            name_dist[row[2].strip()].append(row[0].strip())
        else:
            name_dist[row[2].strip()]=[row[0].strip()]
finaldict={}
for key,value in name_dist.iteritems():
    finaldict[key]=set(value)
```

I want the output to be: `{'APPLE': {'Test', 'Test1'}, 'BALL': {'Test'}}`

Please let me know if there is a better way to get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very new solution

```
from collections import defaultdict
name_dist=defaultdict(set)
with open('test.csv','r')as f:
    spamreader=csv.reader(f,delimiter=",")
    next(f)
    for row in spamreader:
        name_dist[row[2].strip()].add(row[0].strip())
print dict(name_dist) #convert it back to a normal dictionary
```

courtesy of this post [Python: list() as default value for dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755996/python-list-as-default-value-for-dictionary)

Comment: sorry I forgot to assign it to a dictionary haha I have edited the code

Comment: I get attribute error:  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'.

Comment: I have found a completely new solution

Comment: Thanks Hamuel. This works and is much better than my solution.